# Is every point of the constant function $f(x)=k$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ simultaneously a maximum, a minimum, and an inflection point?

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

This topic came up whilst arguing with some colleagues about the following question:

True or false: if a continuous function f defined on closed interval $[a,b]$ then it has a maximum and a minimum.

Some of us said false and giving as a counter-example the constant function. However, some state that it is true.

I found a paper-ette by EHRHARD BEHRENDS, STEFAN GESCHKE, AND TOMASZ NATKANIEC, which supports the true side, however, nothing solid.

My counter argument is that if every point serves as a max, min, and inflection point simultaneously, it is equivalent with no point being one.

Which side is correct?

Comment: Well, what is your definition of the maximum/minimum of a function? Does the constant function have a point satisfying that definition? I don’t really follow your objection that “if every point serves as a max then that is equivalent with no point being one”: if a point is a maximum (i.e., satisfies the definition of a maximum for a function), then it can’t simultaneously *not* be a maximum (i.e., fail to satisfy the same definition).

Comment: Instead of maximum and minimum I would use maximal and minimal. I would say that there is a maximum at $x$ if, for all $y \neq x$ we have $f(y) < f(x)$. A similar statement for minimum. Maximal indicates no point has a larger value. The function $\sin x$ has a maximal value at $\pi /2$.